# How to dynamically show field in RTF template based on the position of another field

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher, xml-publisher, oracle-xml-publisher

We have a requirement in XML Publisher reports by which the RTF template have some field at the bottom of the page. The position of the field from the bottom is based on many attributes(word counts of all the above fields)

The field will be shown in first page or on the second page if the template cant accommodate the field in the first page.

When the field is too big it will move to second page leaving behind large amount of blank space in the first page.
(we have unchecked **Allow row to break across pages** as this field shouldn't split into two pages)

The requirement is if this field is shown on the second page we need to dynamically show some value(like the value will be shown in the second page) in the first page.

Is there anyway we can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to put an if condition, to check the length of the data in the field you are printing, and conditionally print the hard coded text as the last text on page1. You will have to go by trial and error to find the right length where BIP decides to push to page2.

```
<?xdofx:length(char)?> returns the length of char.
```

Comment: Yes but the text getting moved to next page not only depends on this field's length alone. There are many fields on top of this, if those field's length becomes high this field will be moved downwards in page1.
Like if the fields on top of these are of bigger size this field will be moved to second page even if it is of two lines and if the fields on top of these are smaller size this field will be in page 1 even if it is of 3-4 lines.
So is there any way to identify whether any field is there in the same page or not in RTF template ?

Comment: If its more complicated, you will have to use [xsl:fo][1] commands in BIP. Use the pagenumber functions to get which page you are on, and use that to decide if to print a filler message.


  [1]: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10091_01/doc/bip.1013/b40017/T114602T418798.htm#3629942